# Preserve file modification timestamp when downloading with Windows FTP mget command

Tags: batch-file, ftp

My FTP `mget` command is overwriting file modification timestamp, which actually I don't want.

Please help me on this.

**Copy.bat**

```
open 10.198.37.61
user
password
mget *.*
disconnect
quit
```

**Main.bat**

```
ftp -i -s:Copy.bat
```

Comment: Windows `ftp` client is very primitive so you might want to use another one. Anyway it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: For example on FTP server modified date for "test.txt" is 02-11-2015 06:15 AM however when it's getting copied to local system, modified date showing as current datetime

Comment: Yep, that's because Windows `ftp` client is too primitive and can't keep the dates.

Comment: oh...is there any other way to copy file from FTP server with actual modified date automatically

Comment: Find another ftp utility.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows built-in FTP client (`ftp.exe`) cannot preserve timestamp of remote file when downloading (and vice versa).

You have to use another FTP client. Most other FTP clients do preserve the timestamp.

---

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) use the following batch file (`Main.bat`):

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=script.log /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@10.198.37.61/" ^
    "get *.*" ^
    "exit"
```

See also [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score -1):

CoreFTP LE (or PRO) can preserve timestamp - FTP or SFTP

To configure CoreFTP LE:

**Site Manager -> Advanced -> General -> Convert Files to GMT (mark it)**

**Site Manager -> Advanced -> Transfers -> Use MFMT for date modify (mark it)**

Done!

Comment: This is a scripting question (and programming site). A use of GUI applications is not relevant.